# JTextArea not displaying every line outputted to it

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Good evening!
So I am trying to output a list of running processes to the JTextArea.
The piece of code that appends the tasklist is:

```
try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            area.append(line);
            area.append("\n");
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works but it stops after it displays a few processes.
The output window looks like this:
[image: jtextarea appending tasklist]

NOTE:It does display all processes when you output the try catch into the console. So what might be wrong? (I am obviously missing something really dumb here)
Thank you all in advace!

Comment: What your question is???
If it is displaying all processes in console,then what's the problem?Ain't it displaying completely in JTextArea???

Comment: @shekharsuman It doesn't display all processes in JTextArea however it does display them all if you simply output them into the console. The picture that i posted is what it outputs to the JTextArea. There are ALOT more processes to output, trust me. It just doesn't do it.

Comment: In my system,this code is running perfectly---it's giving all the processes running-same as that of console output.NOW,TRUST ME,REALLY!

Comment: What is jTextArea's configuration in your code? Max-Size,min-size,rows,columns,etc???

Comment: @shekharsuman Interesting behaviour that it runs, hmm. Well I've simply set area.setBounds() and nothing else to configure the textarea. Oh and also monospaced font.
    area.setBounds(5,25,972,500); is what I have.

Comment: Even,on turning bounds in my JTextArea I again get the same output---PERFECT OUTPUT RUNNING!!!
I guess you have some other restrictions on your jTextArea!

Comment: Ain't it giving you side scrollbars in the output?
Also,are you using any IDE or using console Java???

Comment: @shekharsuman Any way to remove them somehow? Also im using Eclipse and no it is not giving me scrollbar.

Comment: Also,please add proper tags like `eclipse`,`scrollpane`,etc.which form the basis of your question.This behaviour you found in Eclipse IDE,and your scrolls were missing from jTextArea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is it ain't giving horizontal or vertical sidescrolls in the JTextArea.So,your output is not able to process the extra output which should have been displayed properly.

Interestingly,going as per your `setBounds()` method,my JTextArea returns the perfect output---similar as the one which is getting displayed in the console!!!Also,it is not any problem for your output! The problem seems only with the scrolls which are absent in your code!

Try this one and I hope it helps :-

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setBounds(5,25,972,500);
scrollPane.add(textarea);
scrollPane.setViewportView(textarea);
```

If it doesn't help,please comment.I hope it'll solve your problem.

Best Wishes...

Comment: Thank you! Well it did solve the problem! However it isn't showing the scrollbar not, but it does, in fact, output all processes now. So thanks alot for that, Shekar! Now if I'd just sort out the scrollbar issue that would be awesome! :)
But still, thank you alot for help!

Comment: Why it is not showing scrollbars now??? So peculiar,even after adding code it isn't showing???

Comment: Check whether this `scrollPane.setEnabled(true);` helps you anyhow!

Comment: Also,I would suggest you adding TextArea into your project using drag-and-drop feature of Eclipse.
If not,then try adding `addComponent(JScrollPane1,.......)` to your Defaultlayout,it'll probably help!

Comment: Holy hell I still haven´t figured it out. Really nothing helps. But i found out something interesting. When i resize the window, it shows me this: http://imgur.com/UiuPnM6
This is frustrating.